# core-js dependencies warning [vue]

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, package.json, core-js

I have vue.js application. when using

> yarn install.

Then, warning shows up as below

```
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > apollo > git-parse > babel-polyfill > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
warning @vue/cli > @vue/cli-ui > vue-cli-plugin-apollo > apollo > git-parse > babel-polyfill > babel-runtime > core-js@2.6.11: core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
```

in my `package.json` file, the version of core-js is already ^3

```
    "dependencies": {
...
        "@vue/cli": "^4.2.2",
        "core-js": "^3",
...
    },
```

I wonder if there are anyone who got same issue, and I appreciate it if someone would have any info, any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem with your application or library itself, it's a warning by a dependency of a dependency of a dependency (and so on) of a library you added.

Try perform a security update with:

```
npm audit
or
yarn audit
```

then:

```
npm audit fix
or
yarn audit fix
```

which will try to solve your security issues.

Remember to test everything before committing, because there could be breaking changes.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

I tried 
`yarn audit`

and got 1 vulnerabilities on @vue/cli-service.

so I did
`yarn upgrade @vue/cli-service --latest` 
to fix it. 
Then actually vulnerabilities problem was gone, but still it showed similar waring , saying   

`
core-js@<3 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js@3.
`

Comment: I did `yarn audit fix` also. but it didn't solve vulnerability warning, so I tried upgrade.  Then vulnerability problem was fixed but original problem was not